# disable button typescript with condition

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i want to disable the button with condition, for example i have made a data with the key is the date. I want disable the button for creating a new data that have the same date with data that i already push it to firebase. my code on the html is like this :

```
<button ion-button full (click)="submitLaporan()" color='secondary' [disabled]="isEnabled()">Buat laporan harian</button>
```

and this is the code on typescript :

```
isEnabled()
  {
    this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id).subscribe(laporan =>{
      for(var i =0,j = 0;i<laporan.length;i++)
      {
        console.log("masuk laporan",laporan);
        if(laporan[i].mydate == this.tanggal)  
            return false;
        else
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

on function `isEnabled()` i want to query all data from my firebase and then compare it with the date and if the date on firebase and the date on ionic have the same value it should be return false and the button is disabled. But this is not working at all.

i dont have the data that have the same date with ionic but the button keep disabled. it should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue regarding your `return value` in the for loop. Given the way your code is written, there will be a check only for the first element and if it is equal to `this.tanggal` it will return false, if not it will return `true`.

What you want to achieve is to return `false`, if for all elements, there is no one containing the given date. If an occurrence of the given date is found, it will return `true`.

```
this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id).subscribe(laporan =>{
    let myVal = false;
    for(var i =0,j = 0;i<laporan.length;i++)
          {
            console.log("masuk laporan",laporan);
            if(laporan[i].mydate === this.tanggal)  
                myVal = true;

          }
    return myVal
 })
```

Comment: laporan[i].mydate was string, and this.tanggal is an iso string but i already cut the string, and i think the way that i compare the date is not wrong, because i can show the data that have the same date from firebase and ionic

Comment: Are they string equal ?

Comment: yes the string is equal, i push mydate value from substring of the date

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<button ... [disabled]="isEnabled() | async">Buat laporan harian</button>
```

**typescript**

```
isEnabled() {
    return this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id).switchMap(laporan =>{
      for(let i=0, x=laporan.length; i<x ;i++) {
        console.log("masuk laporan",laporan);

        if(laporan[i].mydate == this.tanggal) {
          return Observable.of(false);
        }
      }
      return Observable.of(true);
    });
}
```

You may need to add these 3 lines:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of }         from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { switchMap }  from 'rxjs/operators';
```